# Matching in python

Tags: python, loops, match

I have two dataframes and want to match both dataframes on below conditions

- State matches between df1 and df2
- pre_year count matches.  i.e if the pre_year is "2018" then column year_2018 in df1 and df2 should match

If match is found in df2 then I want to create a new df with all info from df1. From df2 I want to get ID and post year count (if pre year was 2018, post year would be 2020, if more than 2020 then NA)

Df1

| ID | state | pre_year | year_2018 | year_2019 | year_2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100A | GA | 2018 | 10 | 9 | 7 |
| 300A | FL | 2020 | 5 | 2 | 6 |

Df2

| ID | state | year_2018 | year_2019 | year_2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500A | GA | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 600A | NY | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 700A | FL | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 800A | GA | 10 | 4 | 1 |

expected Final Df

| df_1_ID | df_1_state | df_1_pre_year | df_1_year_2018 | df_1_year_2019 | df_1_year_2020 | df_2_match_ID | df_2_post_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100A | GA | 2018 | 10 | 9 | 7 | 500A | 0 |
| 100A | GA | 2018 | 10 | 9 | 7 | 800A | 1 |

I started with loop but I can't figure out how to match the pre year count

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['100A', '300A'],
                   'state':['GA', 'FL'],
                   'pre_year':[2018, 2020],
                   'year_2018':[10, 5],
                   'year_2019':[9, 2],
                    'year_2020':[7, 6]
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['500A', '600A', '700A', '800A'],
                   'state':['GA', 'NY', 'FL','GA'],
                   'year_2018':[10, 0,0,10],
                   'year_2019':[0,3,0,4],
                    'year_2020':[0,0,0,1]
                   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably some different solutions for your problem. I would first pull the years as a column and the values as a separate with

```py
df2 = df2.melt(id_vars=['ID', 'state'], 
               var_name="year", 
               value_name="value")
df2.year = df2.year.str.replace('year_', '').astype(int)
df2['pre_year'] = df2.year - 2  # calculate the pre_year for the later pd.merge
```

|  | ID | state | year | value | pre_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 500A | GA | 2018 | 10 | 2016 |
| 1 | 600A | NY | 2018 | 0 | 2016 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

with the years column, you can now implement your logic, e.g. with looping over the rows.

You can also add a column with the calculated `pre_year` (done above) and `merge` on `['state', 'pre_year']` with and test if `pre_year+2=year`:

```py
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['state', 'year'], how='left', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))
df = df[df.pre_year+2 == df.year]
```

|  | ID_df1 | state | pre_year | year_2018 | year_2019 | year_2020 | ID_df2 | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100A | GA | 2018 | 10 | 9 | 7 | 500A | 2020 | 0 |
| 1 | 100A | GA | 2018 | 10 | 9 | 7 | 800A | 2020 | 1 |

If needed you can rename the columns or drop columns in a next step.